# How to use having in a window function applied column in the same query?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to use having in the same query without using a subquery to filter the data based on a window function applied column?

This is what I am trying to do -

I have written a query -

```
select
    from_user,
    to_user,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY from_user ORDER BY review_score DESC) as rnk
from airbnb_reviews
WHERE from_type = 'guest'
```

The result -

[image]

Now I am trying to select only the rows where the rnk is 1. I know I can you a subquery to do that but I am looking to do this without using another query. This is what I am trying to do -

```
select
    from_user,
    to_user,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY from_user ORDER BY review_score DESC) as rnk
from airbnb_reviews
WHERE from_type = 'guest'
HAVING rnk = 1
```

Is there any way to do it? And can you explain why I getting an error? What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `HAVING` is for filtering groups.

You have not mentioned your database.  Some databases support the `QUALIFY` clause, which filters window functions.  That would allow you to use:

```
select from_user, to_user,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY from_user ORDER BY review_score DESC) as rnk
from airbnb_reviews
WHERE from_type = 'guest'
QUALIFY rank = 1;
```

Or just:

```
SELECT from_user, to_user
FROM airbnb_reviews
WHERE from_type = 'guest'
QUALIFY DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY from_user ORDER BY review_score DESC) = 1;
```

In databases that do not, you need to use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL. And What do you mean by - "No, HAVING is for filtering groups." The table I showed is truncated, there are more from_user data.

Comment: @bholaprasad . . . Postgres does not support `QUALIFY` (at least not yet).

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is news to me. To your knowledge, what databases support `QUALIFY`?

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . Teradata and Snowflake come to mind.  I don't know if there are others.